# Fixed ImageView size in a custom UITableViewCell swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview, constraints

I am trying to create a cell composed of one button and one imageView inside a UITableView. 
I would like the image to fit the rectangle of the imageView (a square for me) positioned in my storyboard. However, when I load the image via the button and a UIImagePickerController, it fits the cell at its maximum and not the size i would want. I know that the images I am loading are not squared but i want them to be cropped. 
In my case, i would want the image to be shown 80x80 but here is what I get
(I want the image to fit the red square I have drawn) :

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/659430Capturedecran20160303a000145.png

My code when I select the image in my library is :

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
    if let pickedImage = image {
        let cellImage = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 3)) as! ImageCountCell
        cellImage.imageView!.image = pickedImage
        cellImage.imageView!.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        cellImage.imageView!.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, 80, 80)
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.tableView.reloadData();
}
```

I have a custom ImageCountCell class which only has the imageView and the button declared in it.

I have tried many solutions, without success..

It would be nice if someone has one ;)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Don't use cell's imageView property. Instead, create your own image view of the correct size and add it to your cell's contentView.

Comment: If you want to ensure the image is square, you need to use contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill 
Also try cellImage.imageView!.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: @nielsbot You mean I have to delete the imageView from my storyboard and create a UIImageView only with swift code and then add it to my custom cell ?

Comment: In that case, you have to set imageView height and width to fixed size of 80, and set its verticalConstraint to cell so that your imageView would be centre vertically in the cell.

Comment: Did it, nothing changed : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/371764Capturedecran20160303a100720.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to set the clipsToBounds property to true?

```
cellImage.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```